# Is it possible to calculate CPU usage as percent in AWS Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

1. What I want

- Within a container, I want to generate profiling data when CPU usage crosses a threshold.

2. Problems with Container Insight

- Container Insight is unable to monitor each single instance. (as I know)
- It's too slow. It is collected every minute, and the accumulation rate itself is slow. It is difficult to operate in response to overload immediately.

3. cgroup problem

- I tried to calculate cpu usage by referring to this project (https://github.com/daangn/autoprof/blob/main/cgroupv1.go).
- However, the "cpu.cfs_quota_us" information was fixed to -1, so proper calculation was not possible.

Am I doing something wrong?
If not, is there another alternative?

Answer (score 1):

In AWS Fargate, the instances are managed by AWS so it does not support your use case. Fargate can only provide the aggregated (avg,max,min) CPU usage of instances.

You need to use AWS EC2 and publish custom metric from your application for monitoring each instance CPU.